# how to run many task parallel in celery?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, celery-task

I've got function like this :

```
def fetch_data(number):
    ( I/O bound operation .get data from API and insert to Redis )

def starter():
    for i in range(100):
        fetch_data(i)
```

this code takes 250 seconds to finish. I wrote the code with celery, like this :

```
@shared_task
def fetch_data(number):
    ( I/O bound operation. get data from API and insert to Redis )


def starter():
    for i in range(100):
        fetch_data.delay(i)
```

and I start my celery worker with :

```
celery -A my_app worker -l info -c 4
```

it took me about 260 seconds and there isn't any difference in those both ways.
I want to break 260 to 50 seconds. can anyone help me?